# Jquery function that displays list automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my users to select countries from a country list. And when one country is selected, it dissapears from list1 and goes to list2. Here is my code that works:

```
Select countries:<br>
<div name="a1" id="a1"><a style="cursor:pointer" onClick="document.getElementById('f1').style.display='block';addcnt('Bulgaria');">Bulgaria</a><br></div>
<div name="a2" id="a2"><a style="cursor:pointer" onClick="document.getElementById('f2').style.display='block';addcnt('Russia');">Russia</a><br></div>

Selected countries:<br>
<div name="f1" id="f1" style="display: none;"><img  style="cursor:pointer" onClick="document.getElementById('f1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('a1').style.display='block';" src='images/delete.png' /><img src='images/flags/bg.jpg' />Bulgaria</div>
<div name="f2" id="f2" style="display: none;"><img  style="cursor:pointer" onClick="document.getElementById('f2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('a2').style.display='block';" src='images/delete.png' /><img src='images/flags/ru.jpg' />Russia</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script>
$("#a1").click(function ( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).hide();
});
$("#a2").click(function ( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).hide();
});
</script>
```

This is the working part. So i want this countries in a list, showing dynamically in a hidden , and the list to be separeted by comas.Here is the :

```
<div id='countriesvb' style='display:none;'>
<p><b>Countries you've selected</b></p>
</div>
<br /><br />
<form method='post' name='frm'>
<input type='hidden' name='countries' id='countries' value=''>
</form>
```

I tried to make it in the javascript function called "addcnt" to make the list, but something is not working. This is the function

```
function addcnt(ps)
{
var cylist = document.frm.countries.value;
document.frm.countries.value = cylist + ',' + ps;
var khs = document.getElementById('countriesvb').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('countriesvb').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('countriesvb').innerHTML = khs + ps + \"<br />\";
}
```

Can you help me find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because your last statment:

```
document.getElementById('countriesvb').innerHTML = khs + ps + \"<br />\";
```

It's replace the all div and trying to insert text at the end of the div.

try to add this html code to the countriesvb div:

```
<div id='countriesvb' style='display:none;'>
    <p>
        <b>Countries you've selected</b>
    </p>
    <span id="selected-countries"></span> *** you should to add this span.
</div>
```

and try this function instead: 
I just added values to the input and then use the new span to display the values

```
function addcnt(ps)
{
    document.frm.countries.value = !document.frm.countries.value ? ps : document.frm.countries.value + "," + ps;
    var khs = document.frm.countries.value;
    document.getElementById('countriesvb').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('selected-countries').innerHTML = khs;
}
```

here is working example:
 [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyyCm/)